# GUI not showing after installation of 11.10 on virtual machine

Tags: 11.10, installation, boot, login, gui

Steps i did
1.) Specs of VM
    512MB RAM
    20GB  HD
    1Core
2.) Open ISO on VM
3.) Specify Username and password
4.) Boot
5.) Select English
6.) reboot after install
7.) the prompt told me that the ui is being installed
8.) after installation i was directed to the commandline prompt

Comment: Did you by any chance install from the Server ISO?

Answer (score 0):

In vM do you have 3d and 2d checked in the vm settings.
what is the vm graphics memory set at i usually set at 128,
When starting the machine does boot to a terminal. From the terminal log in with your user name and password sudo apt-get install update then try sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop